# Object returned by jpa named query is managed and changes are persisted. How?

Tags: java, jpa

I have an Entity (say Employee) and a find method which uses TypedQuery to execute a named query and return the Employee rows. When the properties of this returned Employee instance is changed it is persisted.

I am trying to figure out the JPA concept behind this and how is this different from update. Is it good to update single row like this if only few column values  of the existing rows in db needs change.
Looking for pointers to JPA concept that explains this.

Here is the code snip.

```
 @Entity
 @NamedQueries({
    @NamedQuery(name = "Employee.findInActiveEmployee", query = "SELECT e FROM Employee e" +
           "WHERE some_prop = :something")
 })
 public class Employee implements Serializable {

 @Id
 @NotNull
 @Column(name = "id")
 private String id;

 @Column(name = "name")
 private int name;

 //so and so properties 
 //getter and setters
 }
```

the finder method

```
TypedQuery<Employee> query = getEntityManager().
            createNamedQuery("Employee.findInActiveEmployee", Employee.class);
    query.setParameter("someproperty", "somevalue");
    try {
        return query.getSingleResult();
    } catch (NoResultException e) {
        throw new NoSuchObjectException("somevalue");
    }
```

Comment: Do you change these properties within a transaction? Then your Employee is connected to a session, which is persisted on commit.

Comment: Yes , the change is within a transaction.

Answer (score 2):

It's not really different from update.

In JPA you usually don't need to explicitly merge changes, since the JPA implementation will keep track of what data has changed in `managed objects` (i.e. entities the `EntityManager` knows about, such as ones that it has just loaded for you) and will make sure to save those changes to the underlying database.

If you don't want that, you can explicitly detach the entity with `em.detach(Object o);`, so the EntityManager no longer manages it . After that you'll need to perform `merge()` to update any changes.

Answer (score 2):

Entities you get back from JPQL-Queries are managed by the EntityManager. In other words, they are atached and there is no need to merge them (like you would need to do for detached entities).
If you alter the entities you got back from the query and you have an open transaction the changes will be committed back to the database.

If you want to update a large number of entities a at the same time or your entities contain some members that have a really large serialized footprint then it might pay of performance-wise to use JPQL Updates.